# angularjs - accessing a factory from a controller in another module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angularjs-injector

This is the factory code under the myApp module

```
angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('userFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

            var userFactory = {};

            userFactory.login = function (user) {
                return $http.post(sc.getDomain() + 'session/create', user);
            };

            return userFactory;
        }]);
```

and the controller is under the myApp.user module

```
angular.module('myApp.user',[])

.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

and this is the main app level module with myApp.user injected -

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myApp.user']). //etc
```

How would I access the factory in the "myApp" module from the controller which is in the "myApp.user" module?

Comment: are you sure you want two apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myApp.user` depends on `myApp`. So `myApp` should be set as a dependency of `myApp.user` instead.

However, this will probably not end up in clean code and I'm not sure how circular dependencies are handled. 
You should move the `userFactory` to `myApp.user` instead.